G-recaptcha stop works and callback function never called
This code worked until last week.
// login.js - Perform AJAX login on form submit`
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    
    const isRecaptchaEnabled = true; // add to enable or disable recaptcha check to avoid this recaptcha lock issues.
    
  
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#btn-login', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ( isRecaptchaEnabled ) {
            if (checkFields() === false) {
                grecaptcha.reset();
            } else {
                // never here
                grecaptcha.execute();
            }
        } else {
            ajax_login('');
        }
    });
});

var notify = null;
var loggedin = false;
var redirect = null;

function checkFields() {
    if (jQuery('#user_login').val() !== "" && jQuery('#user_pass').val() !== "") {

        return true;

    } else {

        var msg = 'Fill username e password to login...';
        if (jQuery('#user_login').val() !== "" && jQuery('#user_pass').val() === "") {
            msg = 'Enter password for your account';
        }

        toastr['error'](msg, 'Login Failed');

        return false;

    }
}

function ajax_login(token) {
    var data = [];

    data.push(
        { name: 'action', value: 'login' },
        { name: 'user_login', value: jQuery('form#loginform #user_login').val() },
        { name: 'user_password', value: jQuery('form#loginform #user_pass').val() },
        { name: 'fp_security', value: jQuery('form#loginform #fp_security').val() },
    );

    if ('' !== token) {
        data.push({ name: 'captcha', value: token });
    }

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            toastr.remove();
            toastr['info']('Login...', 'Wait please');
        },
        success: function (res) {
            loggedin = res.loggedin;
            redirect = res.redirect;
            if (loggedin === true) {
                toastr.remove();
                toastr['success'](res.message, 'Login Success');
                if (redirect !== false) {
                    document.location.href = redirect;
                } else {
                    document.location.href = document.location.href;
                }
            } else {
                toastr.remove();
                toastr['error'](res.message, 'Login Failed');
            }
            grecaptcha.reset();
        },
        error: function () {
            toastr.remove();
            toastr['error']('Something goes wrong. Reload the page.', 'Complete!');
        },
    });
}

var onSubmit = function (token) {
    console.log(token);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        ajax_login(token);
    });
}

var onloadCallback = function () {
    console.log("Captcha Loading V2...")
    grecaptcha.render('recaptcha',
        {
            'sitekey': 'MYKEY',
            "size": "invisible",
            "callback": onSubmit,
        }
    );
};

I tried clearing the cache, emptying cookies, using different browsers. Nothing to do, it doesn't want to know about validating logins anymore.
The recaptcha is loaded and the google badge is shown on the page, but when I enter the login data, the button no longer runs the callback (onSubmit function callback) that sends the ajax request for login.
If I disable google recaptcha, setting the flag to false, obviously everything works correctly and I can log in again.
I tried changing the keys using new ones, I also checked the domain associations, and everything is fine.
Can anyone explain to me if there is something that has changed in the meantime?
I should point out that I use the same js file on different projects, but only on this one the callback is never invoked.
The ajax call does not start at all, so I exclude a server-side verification problem, also because until next week it was working correctly, and if I disable recaptcha the login is done correctly.
What can I check?
